# Devise redirect on sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I know this question was asked several times. I tried them but none of them solved my problem. I used devise for users. I want to redirect the user to a different page on sign up rather than signing in directly. I created registration controller, and tried overriding "after_inactive_sign_up_path_for" but it didn't work out. I 'm using devise confirmable also. So until the user is verified I should redirect him to other page.

registrations_controller.rb

```
    class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
      protected

      def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        "http://www.google.com" # Or :prefix_to_your_route
      end
    end
```

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
```

Next I tried to move the registrations into a different folder in the controllers folder. But that too didn't work out.

FYI: I'm using rails 5 and devise 4.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should be in the path `app/controllers/users/registrations_controllers.rb`.

Then your routes should be

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }
```